# CrossWord Puzzle getting error: no match for ‘operator==’

Tags: c++

Firstly I would like to say sorry if this is a repost, onto the question.
I'm new with c++ stl and got stuck at this point.
I have created this function for solving crossword puzzle in c++ but it is showing me the

prog.cpp:17:49: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<char >::value_type {aka char}’)

if(matrix[i][j]=='-' || matrix[i][j]==word[0])

```cpp
void solve(vector<vector<string>> &matrix,vector<string> &puzzleWords,int idx)
{
    if(idx==puzzleWords.size())
    {
        return;
    }
    string word=puzzleWords[idx];
    for(int i=0;i<matrix.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].size();j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]=='-' || matrix[i][j]==word[0])
            {
                if(canPlacedHorizontally(matrix,word,i,j))
                {
                    vector<bool> wePlaced=placeWordHorizontally(matrix,word,i,j);
                    solution(matrix,word,idx+1);
                    unplaceWordHorizontally(matrix,wePlaced,i,j);
                }
                
                if(canPlacedVertically(matrix,word,i,j))
                {
                    vector<bool> wePlaced=placeWordVertically(matrix,word,i,j);
                    solution(matrix,word,idx+1);
                    unplaceWordVertically(matrix,wePlaced,i,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearly getting confused between strings (which are sequences of characters) and chars (which are individual characters).

Look at this code

```
if(matrix[i][j]=='-' || matrix[i][j]==word[0])
```

`matrix[i][j]` is a string (because `matrix` is a 2D vector of strings) but `'-'` is a char and `word[0]` is a char (because `word` is a string). You can't compare a string and a char for equality.

You have a 2D vector for your crossword, but each square of that crossword is a string. Most crosswords you can only write a single letter in each square, so probably you should have this

```
void solve(vector<vector<char>> &matrix,vector<string> &puzzleWords,int idx)
```

With that change the if statement above will compile because you will be comparing chars with chars, not chars with strings.